# Call php function for a REST service in the same code from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, rest

I am writing a chrome extension where javascript code talks to my backend. My backend is exposed via an endpoint accessible via GET url call.

The issue i am facing is i am not able to go one directory up to access my endpoint entry file. I copied the file into same directory and tried to get the data, but it is printing the entire file.

Directory Structure:

```
\Root
 --backend
    ----api.php
 --Chrome Extn
    ----resource.js
    ----popup.html
```

Now when i hit http:///api.php it gives me a json and i want the same to be as a object in my javascript call. Since it is not a cross domain file, but a file residing on local, i used the following way:

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../api.php" ,
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Now since this failed, i copied api.php to Chrome Extn. directory, but this one is simply echoing the code.

All i need to do is use the data from the api.php and parse it.

Comment: url should be a url, not a filepath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I used external URL in permissions of manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "app-name",
    "description" : "app=desc",
    "version" : "1.1.1",
    "browser_action" : {
        "default_icon" : "icon.png",
        "default_popup" : "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions" : [
        "tabs",
        "bookmarks",
        "activeTab",
        "http://www.externalUrl.com/subdir"
    ],
    "icons" : {
        "16" : "16.png",
        "24" : "24.png",
        "128" : "128.png"
    }
}
```